How do I make data from another form available?
I am working on a ERP system and I want to make multiple use Tool Strip Bar look like this

The buttons on the Tool Strip can control the events on other forms (I set the Tool Strip on main form) so the buttons can control functions like add data, save data, edit data, delete data.
I want to add data with the buttons on the tool strip, but I can't since my input is in "form2" but the tool strip and I don't know how to make the data available between "form1" and "form2".
I type in the inputs in "form2" and I want to save the inputs into my database with buttons on the tool strip (which I set it on "form1")
Don't know the right way to handle this situation


If you want to execute functionality on Form2 by clicking on the Toolbar on Form1 give Form1 a surface of methods/properties etc. that can be called by Form2 todo the stuff needed on Form1. Forms are also more or less just classes that should and can be used the same pattern.

Try to change all controls in form2  (in properties window) so Modifiers become public. Then you can access them like: form2.MyControl.
